# PHP: Loop through text file and isolate lines which a specific "starting point"

Tags: php, text, for-loop, loops

I’m trying to reduce some editing time within some textfiles where there approximately are 10.000 lines of text, but I only need around 200 or some.

The text file relies on a almost specific pattern but it deviates from time to time but my “focus” in order to select the right line to keep is, that the line always starts with: **z3455** and then have a variable afterwards, e.g.: z3455 http://url.com/data1/data1.1/data1.3/ (342kb)

I have an algorithm to capture the URL and its content but now I need some way to loop through the text file, deleting all lines **except** does that starts with **z3455** and then “push” them together so they are listed underneath each other.

I’ve tried different approaches for this in PHP but can’t seem to find a correct function. I can “isolate” a specific line number but when it deviates I can’t use this approach fully.

I hope that someone can help me, either by providing the code or knocking me in the right direction to how I’ll solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Sincerely
- Mestika

Comment: Could you maybe show some things you've tried?  Even if it's pseudo-code it will be better if we aren't unknowingly duplicating your work.

Comment: It's common for a decent text editor program to let you use regular expressions to search/replace in files. You can even do it for all files in a directory, and have it go step by step so you can baby sit its actions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$in = fopen('file.txt', 'rb')
$out = fopen('filtered.txt', 'wb+')
while($line = fread($in)) {
    if (preg_match('/^z3455 http.*$/', $line)) {
         fwrite($out, $line);
    }
}
```

Of course, if you're running this from the command line, you might as well just skip PHP and use grep, which'd be far more efficient:

```
$ grep '^z3455 http' file.txt > filtered.txt
```

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks a lot for your help. I took your code and modified it a bit, then it worked like a charm.
I hadn't considered using regular expressions (of some reason) but it of cause make great sense to do so.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. `substr` should be faster than regex here, especially on a big file.

```
foreach (file($file) as $line) {
    if (substr($line, 0, 5) != 'z3455') {
        continue;
    }
    // $line is now a line of text that starts with 'z3455.
    // Do with it whatever you need. If you want whatever comes
    // after z3455, you could then do $line = substr($line, 5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just first idea I had in my head (very basic & untested):

```
<?php
$filename = 'foo.txt';
$file = file($filename);
$matchedLines = array();

foreach($file as $line) {
  if(preg_match('/^z3455/', $line)) {
    $matchesLines[] = $line;
  }
}
?>
```